# How to use notification channels created via terraform into alert policies with for_each

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am creating gcp notification channels using terraform
example :notification_channels.tf

```
resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "alert_notification_opsgenie_channel" {
  for_each = { for inst in var.notification_channels : inst.display_name => inst }
  display_name = each.value.display_name
  type = "webhook_tokenauth"
  labels = {
    "url" = each.value.url
  }
  enabled = each.value.enabled
}
```

I have to use these created notification channels in configuring gcp alert policies

example alert_policy.tf:

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "business_metric_alert_policy" {
  for_each = { for inst in var.business_metric_alert_policies : inst.display_name => inst }
  display_name = each.value.display_name
  combiner = "OR"
  conditions {
    display_name = each.value.condition_display_name
    condition_threshold {
      filter = each.value.filter
      duration = each.value.duration
      comparison = each.value.comparison
      threshold_value = each.value.threshold_value
      trigger {
          count = each.value.trigger_count
      }
      aggregations {
        alignment_period = each.value.alignment_period
        per_series_aligner = each.value.per_series_aligner
        cross_series_reducer = each.value.cross_series_reducer
      }
    }
  }
  notification_channels = << how to get notification channels here >>
}
```

this creates multiple alert policy resources, which may contain any number of notification channels.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
notification_channels = google_monitoring_notification_channel.alert_notification_opsgenie_channel.*.id
```

Here you can find more details and an explanation,
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/solved-unclear-syntax-in-tf-0-12-for-lists-from-count-based-resources/6417

Comment: How is `business_metric_alert_policy` an instance of `google_monitoring_notification_channel` resource ?

Comment: You right, what I mean was
notification_channels = google_monitoring_notification_channel. alert_notification_opsgenie_channel.*.id